Dynamic text color on hover based on fetched values
I am not sure why applying className based on the value fetched from the database and then using this value in css for custom color on hover doesn't work. Could you help? 
An example of the category would be 'Literature' --> lowercased 'literature'. This class is getting correctly assigned when I inspect but somehow the content of the class is not being displayed properly:

Part of the tsx file:
<ul className={`${style.categories} ${poppins.className}`}>
    {unique_categories.map((category) => (
        <li key={category.id}>
            <Link
                href={`${category}`.toLowerCase()}
                className={`${category}`.toLowerCase()}>
                {category}
            </Link>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>

Part of the css file:
.categories {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.categories li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}

.categories a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.literature:hover {
  color: blue !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}


Instead of pasting the TSX code, paste the resulting HTML. Your question is not clear: what values? What classes? How does the class looks like rendered? What colors? Please create a [mre].

@RokoC.Buljan I added information: An example of the category would be 'Literature' --> lowercased 'literature'. Should I pass color on hover in html then?

Is category a string? What class is set when your inspect the element in developer tools?

Please, provide the rendered code because from what you think it does not work - it actually works: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/nqf4wm03/ At least from what you described so far. Please read again the first comment. Perhaps Next did not caught your styles correctly?

@htor - I can see the class being assigned correctly via Inspect

@NorahJones Are you using CSS modules? See the answer given below if so. Otherwise, inspect upwards in the DOM the applied CSS rules under Inspect>Elements. Avoid using !important if you can.

if you're using css modules in your project the classnames returned from the import are not equal to what you wrote. eg.
.test{
  display: block;
}

the test classname will become something like test--a12d.
you can eather use :global to make the classname be the same or just plain import your CSS file:
:global {
  .literature:hover {
    color: blue !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
  }
}

or
import 'colorClasses.css' // instead of import styles from 'colorClasses.module.css'

